# what means this statement in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL dumped File. it contains SQL statements for building tables and inserting data. I want run these statements in SQL server and use data. but there are some constraints that sql server don't know them. for example can someone help me to understand the mean of below constraint?

```
CREATE TABLE borders (
    country1 character varying(4) NOT NULL,
    country2 character varying(4) NOT NULL,
    length numeric,
    search_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT borders_length_check CHECK ((length > (0)::numeric))
);
```

Comment: Looks like it's just a constraint to insure that the `length` field is greater than 0. In sql-server it would probably just be `CONSTRAINT borders_length_check CHECK (length> 0)`

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the code you provided will create a table, but not as it's coded in SQL Server. You would need to change a few pieces. Below should produce a similar result in SQL SERVER:

```
CREATE TABLE borders (
    country1 varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    country2 varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    length bigint,
    search_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT borders_length_check CHECK (length > 0)
);
```

The constraint makes sure that if a value is provided for length, a positive value is inserted into the table. If no value is entered it remains null.

I edited the last comment based on the comments below.

Comment: "*makes sure that a length is entered*" no, it does not. You can still store `NULL` in that column - but that's the same as the original table definition.

Comment: So if data is inserted and length is entered as NULL, that value will be considered greater than 0 and allowed as a record entry?

Comment: `null` is neither greater than nor less than zero. So the check constraint is no not false and thus you can insert the row. But yes: you will be allowed to insert rows where length is null.

Comment: You can not enter a `length` values that is less than 0. If you want to enforce a positive length for every record, a `NOT NULL` constraint has to be added.